# What happens when you say Object someObject = otherSameObject;

Tags: java, swing, serialization, constructor

I'm making an application in Java using a JTabbedFrame. Each tab is created by a separate class extending JFrame. I would like to save each tab's state by saving the object to a file on window close and read them back from the file when the tabs are created. I know when you serialize an object all the instance variables are saved, but what happens to the constructor? When I say for example in the class that builds the tab frame:

```
public class Jtab{
    private ClassThatExtendsJFrame tab;

    public Jtab(ClassThatExtendsJFrame tab){  

         this.tab = tab; // what happens here? Is the constructor called?
         JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
         tabs.addTab("name", icon, this.tab, "tooltip");
    }

}
```

All of the code that lays out the JFrame is currently in the constructor. All of the JLabels and elements in the the layout are properties of the class which I assign in the constructor. So I see there are two options that might happen: The constructor is called and all the variables are reset, or the constructor is not called and and my layout is not created. What's the best way to accomplish what I am looking to do?

Comment: The first thing you need to know is every variable is a pointer to some point in memory. When you assign one variable to another, you are actually assigning the memory address of the variable on the right to the variable on the left. To means that know both variables point to the same location in memory and to what ever is contained there...

Comment: So, does that mean the these places in memory automatically know where they are supposed to be positioned on the screen?

Comment: No. The object knows this information (via its properties, which are stored in memory). Positioning is determined by a number of different factors which doesn't directly relate to the question...

Comment: So I would need to call some other method to set the layout, but the JLabels and textfields would have the data when they were saved.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to assign a layout manager, which would update the components of the container according to its requirements. What do you mean *"when they are saved"*? An object is a self contained entity, so yes, once applied, those values will be maintained by the object itself and all references to the same object (or memory location) will have the same information, as it's the same data ...

Comment: So for example I have a JLabel which default will have a text value of ">>>". During the use of the program the text will change to "XXX". I then save the object to a file using object serialization. When the program is run again I will read the object back in and assign it to that JTab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59688/discussion-between-craig-smith-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 2):

You can never say object = object since the left side of an assignment expression cannot be an "object". Rather it is a reference variable of some type. So instead you can only do variable gets assigned object reference. Or variable gets compared to another variable reference.

Comment: More specifically, the left side of the assignment is a reference variable that must always either be null or be a pointer to some object of appropriate class.

Answer (score 2):

you are saying

```
this.tab = tab;
```

they are two different references.

this.tab refers to the field of the class

tab refers to the parameter of the constructor.

thus you are assigning the reference referred by the parameter to the field.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you are assigning a local field to the value passed into the constructor where the field and the local variable have the same name -

```
public Jtab(ClassThatExtendsJFrame tab){  
     this.tab = tab; // assign tab from the argument to this instance's field
```

Could also be written as

```
public Jtab(ClassThatExtendsJFrame that{  
     tab = that; // <-- this.tab
```

Again, the `this` was to overcome the name collision.